# Installing JupyterNotebook but instead, a lot of WARNINGs

Tags: macos, python-2.7, installation, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install JupyterNotebook on my Mac via terminal. After trying to install the application, I didn't get any message informing that the installation was complete.

```
pip install jupyterlab
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python -m pip install jupyter --ignore-installed six --user
```

Then I got the following ERROR and WANRING message:

```
ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
 WARNING: The scripts jupyter, jupyter-migrate and jupyter-troubleshoot are installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jupyter-kernel, jupyter-kernelspec and jupyter-run are installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script pygmentize is installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts iptest, iptest2, ipython and ipython2 are installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jupyter-console is installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jsonschema is installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jupyter-trust is installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jupyter-nbconvert is installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jupyter-bundlerextension, jupyter-nbextension, jupyter-notebook and jupyter-serverextension are installed in '/Users/ksb7640/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

This was followed by

```
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Send2Trash-1.5.0 appnope-0.1.0 attrs-19.1.0 backports-abc-0.5 backports.shutil-get-terminal-size-1.0.0 bleach-3.1.0 configparser-3.8.1 decorator-4.4.0 defusedxml-0.6.0 entrypoints-0.3 enum34-1.1.6 functools32-3.2.3.post2 futures-3.3.0 ipaddress-1.0.22 ipykernel-4.10.1 ipython-5.8.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 ipywidgets-7.5.1 jinja2-2.10.1 jsonschema-3.0.2 jupyter-1.0.0 jupyter-client-5.3.1 jupyter-console-5.2.0 jupyter-core-4.5.0 mistune-0.8.4 nbconvert-5.6.0 nbformat-4.4.0 notebook-5.7.8 pandocfilters-1.4.2 pathlib2-2.3.4 pexpect-4.7.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 prometheus-client-0.7.1 prompt-toolkit-1.0.16 ptyprocess-0.6.0 pygments-2.4.2 pyrsistent-0.15.4 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pyzmq-18.1.0 qtconsole-4.5.4 scandir-1.10.0 setuptools-41.2.0 simplegeneric-0.8.1 singledispatch-3.4.0.3 six-1.12.0 terminado-0.8.2 testpath-0.4.2 tornado-5.1.1 traitlets-4.3.2 wcwidth-0.1.7 webencodings-0.5.1 widgetsnbextension-3.5.1
```

So then I tried

```
sudo pip install nose
```

Then got

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/man'
```

I was expecting to have an application installed on my Mac with which I can just double click the logo and start the application, like Chrome with that Circular google logo. What should I do from here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing anaconda.